# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot read from a closed TextReader.'

Tags: c#

For my homework I have to make a XAML project using a csv file to show pictures of zoo animals along with other info which is included in the code.

It's almost done but when I run the program it gives me this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot read from a closed TextReader.'

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file == null)
    {
        tbFileStatus.Text = "(not a valid file chosen)";
        return;
    }

    tbFileStatus.Text = file.Path;

    using (var fileAccess = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        using (var stream = fileAccess.AsStreamForRead())
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    var lvAnimals = csv.GetRecords<Animal>();
                }

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var row = reader.ReadLine();
                    var parts = row.Split(',');
                    var number = (parts[0]);
                    var name = parts[1];
                    var species = parts[2];
                    var latin_name = parts[3];
                    var cage = parts[4];
                    var picture = parts[5];
                    var llvAnimals = new Animal
                    {
                        Number = number,
                        Name = name,
                        Species = species,
                        Latin_Name = latin_name,
                        Cage = cage,
                        Picture = picture
                    };
                    lvAnimals.ItemsSource = llvAnimals;
                }                                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When debugging what line does your error occur on?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your `StreamReader` to the `CsvReader`.

```
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    ...
}
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
...
```

By making use of `using`, you are disposing the `CsvReader` after its usage. Keep in mind, that some implementations like this also disposing their readers. This can be seen in the corresponding [implementation](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs#L1335). This means, the passed `StreamReader` gets also closed and can't be used afterwards. This causes the *System.ObjectDisposedException*.

To solve this, extend the usage scope like this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    ...
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    ...
}
```

Comment: or call the constructor like `new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true)`, it accepts a `leaveOpen` bool